# php preg_match non greedy?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string (from a file):

```
ILX (New for 2013!)

Overview: The least expensive route to Honda's premium-label goodness

Drivetrain: Two four-cylinder engines to choose from as well as a gas-electric hybrid; front-wheel-drive only.
```

How I get the string:

```
$writeup = file_get_contents($car_files_path . $manufacture . '/Stories/'.$story);
```

I want to match the overview line (`Overview: The least expensive route to Honda's premium-label goodness)`. What is the best way to achieve this.

I tried .*\n, but that will match everything and then a new line. Is there a way to make regex non-greedy?

I have tried:
`preg_match('/^Overview:\s.*$/im', $writeup, $overall_matches)` and I don't get any matches

Comment: Non-greedy is `.*?` http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to match .. just the entire line with the word `Overview` in it, the newline?  What is your actual regex?

Comment: I am trying to match the entire line with Overview:

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add `?` after the quantifier to make it ungreedy. In this case, your regex would be `.*?\n`.

To specifically match the line beginning with "Overview: ", use this regex:

```
/^Overview:\s.*$/im
```

The `m` modifier allows `^` and `$` to match the start and end of lines instead of the entire search string. Note that there is no need to make it ungreedy since `.` does not match newlines unless you use the `s` modifier - in fact, making it ungreedy here would be bad for performance.

Comment: I forgot to include part of the string. Please see update

Comment: It should still work fine.

Comment: I am still not getting any matches. See update above

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://adamhaskell.net/img/php-regex.png)

Comment: I am doing this:

    $writeup = file_get_contents($car_files_path . $manufacture . '/Stories/'.$story);

Comment: I think somehow doing file_get_contents causes something to act odd.

Comment: The file had CR instead of LF for line endings. A simple str_replace did the trick

Comment: Works for `+` too ! ( `.+?` )

Comment: Why does ? character changes working of regex?