# php regex preg_match - stop after first delimiter

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a text with a lot of words and links. I want to find a specific link inside it. I currently use:

```
preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.myserver\.com\/.*\.(rar|zip|tar|gz)/',$text,$result)
```

Now let's say i have this text:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <a href="http://www.myserver.com/test.zip">http://www.myserver.com/somefile.zip</a> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

the expected result would be:

> http://www.myserver.com/test.zip

But the script will return:

```
http://www.myserver.com/test.zip">http://www.myserver.com/somefile.zip
```

I suppose i need to tell it to stop after reaching the first ".zip" but... how ?

Answer (score 2):

The problems is that `preg_match` by default is **greedy**. This means it will match as much of the string as possible.

If you add a `?` to a quantifier, it will make it non-greedy, meaning "stop where the next pattern begins"

```
preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.myserver\.com\/.*?\.(rar|zip|tar|gz)/',$text,$result);
//                                      ----^
```

See also:

- [php preg_match non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967485/php-preg-match-non-greedy)
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Don't know what I was thinking... Thanks for the fix!