# Finding a regex to match [foo]

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the approriate regex to match with [*whatever*].
For instance, I want [foo foo2 foo3 foo4], [], [foo] to match.
So far I've come up with this : `#^\[.*\]$#`, but I can't find out what's wrong.
Thanks for the help !
Edit : Problem is different than [php preg_match non greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967485/php-preg-match-non-greedy) because I need [ ] at the start/end of the string.
Edit 2 : found the solution : `^\\[.*\\]$`, however I don't know why I need to double the `\`. If anyone could explain, it would be cool.

Comment: try this :  \[?(foo\d?\s?)*\]?

Comment: Doesn't work. Also when I write foo it means anything. So I think I should use `.` somewhere

Comment: If it is PHP, you do not need to double backslashes, just use `''` around the regex.