# Extract urls from a string

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
http://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8/https://www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux
```

And I want to extract urls separate from this.

My code:

```
$pattern = '@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)@';

$str= "http://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8/https://www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux";

if($num_found = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out))
{
  echo "FOUND ".$num_found." LINKS:\n";
  print_r($out[0]);
}
```

But the output is wrong:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8/https
    [1] => www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux
)
```

I want to output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8
    [1] => https://www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux
)
```

Please help

Comment: you could just split on http(s):// should be enough. you dont really need the rest

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: You are posting a link to an **illegal copy** of a _bones_ episode. -1

Comment: You probably want a [non-greedy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967485/php-preg-match-non-greedy) - I tried to test this out, but https://regex101.com/ doesn't like your existing string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe don't have fun with statements etc. and do it by function [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)?

Eg.
`$urls = preg_split('/ (http|https) /', $str, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

**EDIT**

To do this you must add new flag + add results to each other.

```
$urls = preg_split('/(http|https)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($urls as $k => $v) {
    if ($k % 2 != 0) {
        continue;
    }
    $list[] = $urls[$k].$urls[$k+1];
}
```

Comment: This is the result:

 [1] => ://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8/
 [2] => s://www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux

Comment: I want to keep http and https to links

Comment: see my edit, it contains correct code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str= "http://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8/https://www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux";


$foo = preg_split('#(http://)|(https://)#', $str,0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);



for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($foo); $i += 2) {
    $delim = isset($foo[$i + 1]) ? $foo[$i + 1] : '';
    $tmp[] = $foo[$i] . $delim;
}
print_r($tmp);
```

> Array (
>       [0] => http://sh.st/st/8052f1bbc624add41cd2a6236f76cfc8/
>       [1] => https://www.rapidvideo.com/embed/o1cTaZbux 
> )